# JTextArea auto height resize

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, layout-manager, boxlayout

All component widths are same.
I have a JPanel (box layout; PAGE_AXIS).
I have added a Box.filler on it which has following specifications:

Min size(height) -1

Preferred size(height) JPanel height

Maximim size(height) JPanel height

I added JTextArea with border 7 pixels thick (only below).

When I type in text, the JTextArea expands, but not enough, and after a couple of lines the text goes off bounds (you can't see it anymore).

I can determine how many lines of text exist (using FontMetrics), and I can force setSize accordingly, but nothing really changes. Printing out JTextArea.getHeight() does show that the size has changed on my terms, but visually it stays as if it didn't. And I haven't forgot validating and repainting.

How can I force the JTextArea to resize to certain size?

Comment: 1) What is your question? 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) You might look to use a multi-line (HTML formatted) label instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alternatively just make the JTextArea wrap words?:

```
JTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

you could also try setting the amount of rows using `setRows(int rows)` and then `revalidate()` and `repaint()`

Comment: Karlovsky writes about lines, not columns, that go off bounds.

Comment: @StefanNeubert true see edietd post

Answer (score 0):

You could put the JTextArea into a JScrollPane to keep the additional lines visible without changing the space the JTextArea needs on screen.

See the Oracle Tutorial on [how to use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more information.